# Understanding the minimal primary decomposition of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

A decomposition of an ideal into to primary ideals $q= \bigcap q_i$ is said to be minimal if:

- the radical of each $q_i$ is distinct
- if $q_i \nsupseteq \cap _{i\neq j } q_j$

I'm trying to what the second condition really means. I know for example the first condition does not hold if we took in $\mathbb Z$ $q=(3)\cap(3^2)\cap(3^5)$. I cannot think of any clean example to see what the second condition means.

I think perhaps one reason I am struggling is in general not all ideals have a primary decomposition. It also seems that even if an ideal has a primary decomposition it need not be unique. Is there an obvious way to find a minimal decomposition given a non-minimal decomposition?

Comment: If you have a primary decomposition $I = \bigcap_j q_j$ but $q_i \supseteq \bigcap_{j \neq i} q_j$, then $q_i$ is redundant, in that $\bigcap_j q_j = \bigcap_{j \neq i} q_j$, so omitting $q_i$ still gives a primary decomposition. This Wikipedia article has a good explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition#Primary_decomposition_of_an_ideal

Comment: Thanks that made alot more sense seeing it phrases that way